# Django Black Not Installing Properly in Pipenv environment

Tags: python, django, pipenv

I received an error after installing Django Black. I ran `pipenv install black --pre`. Then when I ran `manage.py runserver`, I received the error below. Note that I am running Windows 10.

```
from custom_storages import MediaStorage
File "C:\Users\dgold2\Documents\py\ibankai\src\custom_storages.py", line 2, in <module>
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage
File "C:\Users\dgold2\Documents\py\ibankai\src\.venv\lib\site-packages\storages\backends\s3boto3.py", line 18, in <module>
from django.utils.six.moves.urllib import parse as urlparse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.utils.six'
```

Comment: Try using [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) instead.

Comment: Also I assume you ran `python3 manage.py runserver` right?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am running the command above and I don't think I'm ready to abandon pipenv for virtualenv. Many other packages are running fine with my current configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this when I was using a template for Django + Vue on Heroku, the only difference being that in my case the error was thrown by whitenoise, a static files middleware, rather than s3boto3. The root cause is that my Pipfile specified `Django = "*"` but `whitenoise = "==4.0"`. So pipenv was grabbing the most recent available Django, which was 3.0, but whitenoise 4 was trying to import from `django.utils.six` (like your s3boto3 package), which seems to have been deprecated in Django 3. (Compare [2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/utils/six/), [3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/)).

See if there's a s3boto3 version specifier in your Pipfile that you can update, or alternatively specify `Django ="2.2"` if you're willing to hold off on Django 3.